# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: database, oracle10g, tns

I'm very new on Database subjects and trying to do some beginner stuff with connecting from Netbeans. but when i test my connection i'm facing with some error (i searched this error but couldnt understand anything). i installed `Oracle 10g Express Database Edition` and downloaded `ojdbc6.jar` for `Oracle Thin`. this my simple code just for test the driver version;

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

    class JDBCVersion
    {
      public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException
      {
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE [hr on HR]");
        Connection conn = ods.getConnection();

        // Create Oracle DatabaseMetaData object
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();

        // gets driver info:
        System.out.println("JDBC driver version is " + meta.getDriverVersion());
      }
    }
```

and i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

as i said i am newbie about this database stuff and i will be very glad if you can help with explaining. thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code on how to connect to your Oracle Database:

```
public class JDBCVersion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "username",
                "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
}
```

Where username and password have to be changed accordingly. Also if you have installed Oracle 10g then the right version would be ojdbc14.jar.

Comment: wow it worked!. thanks a lot. by the way does ojdbc14 library has important differences from ojdbc6 _?

Comment: actually ojdbc6.jar works but it is actually driver for Oracle 11g. So better to use the right version since you are using Oracle 10g